# ASP.NET MVC - How to best build a form action that can respond in many ways?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of writing a web app that includes a reporting form. This form contains a number of radio buttons that allow the user to specify the return data.
There are about 6 different return data 'formats', and each of those has two variations - html data or JSON data for rendering to a chart.

I have begun coding it up and already my form post action method feels wrong.
I basically have a check on the requested data format and return it as needed. Each return type requires its own partial view / json object so there is little room for reusing code.

It feels like each one should have its own action method. Having the form post to different locations based on a radio button choice also feels wrong though.

Switching on report type and then redirecting to the appropriate action in the controller also feels like its not quite right.

Am I approaching this in the wrong way? As it currently stands my controller action contains a lot of code and a lot of logic...

Hope my query makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you handle the post in client-side javascript, which indeed calls a different action depending on the report chosen by the user? jQuery could help with that.

Comment: I could do. But I'd rather keep the JS as dumb as possible. That's just my preference though :-) I can see if working if I modified the form action with each radio button seleciton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach. To maximize reuse you could:

- include reusable templates inside your views
- make sure the business/data layer code is the same everywhere (where possible)

I suppose the views you need to return actually *are* different for each combination of options so whatever approach you take, you are stuck with that.

I wouldn't opt for the client-side approach. You then have code on both the server and the client that has to be updated whenever you change anything. I would keep the code that receives a set of options and determines what to do with them in one place.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I kind agree with the not fiddling the client side as that would become a chore to maintain. I'm now thinking that one action method which delegated to others is the way to go...there is no real way of doing this is a neat way I think... :)

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean about it feeling like each format should be a separate action, but maybe a hybrid approach would make it feel better.

If you set the value of each radiobutton to the name of the action it relates to, you then, in your main POST action, have a parameter that you can use to call the appropriate action in one line of code. You don't have to fudge anything in Javascript, it's easily extensible, and you get your separate actions.

Comment: hmm yeah I kinda thought about this - so a switch maybe in the main form action method and then a redirecttoaction to the appropriate action method?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right you have a lot of switch code in action.

I think you can use Factory pattern. You can create factory that will accept switch parameter as parameter and will return ActionResult instance.